# Comparing two columns in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-restrictions

I have a table in Postgre Database. The table has 2 timestamp format columns. I need those rows where one column timestamp is not equals the second column timestamp.

For the below query I need the Hibernate criteria restrictions.

select * from A where column1<>column2

Comment: You don't actually compare columns; you compare values of "fields". Does a value for a row in column1 or column2 change? Or is it set once and never changed?

Comment: Yes they are different values. In actual scenario they are createdTime and UpdatedTime. I need the rows where createdTime is not equal to UpdatedTime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58913450/comparing-two-columns-in-hibernate-criteria?noredirect=1#comment104089122_58913450), you'll have to do a full table scan, which will create troubles with a bigger table. You will likely need to change your approach altogether, and introduce a field which says something like "IsUpdated". Or, when creating that record, `UpdatedTime` should be set to null, indicating it hasn't been updated yet. Then, you can do a query like "give all records where UpdatedTime is not null".

Comment: Thanks Haris. This looks like a good approach. However, we already have the columns with the data in both the columns and hence we cannot use this approach.

Comment: @Bhupesh Mathur Then you can simply update the records in your database, and use an approach which is fast enough. You can easily do some benchmarking to prove which approach is better and faster.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like that?

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Foo> cQuery = builder.createQuery(Foo.class);
Root<Foo> from = cQuery.from(Foo.class);
CriteriaQuery<Foo> select = cQuery.select(from);
select.where(builder.notEqual(from.get("col1"), from.get("col2")));
List<Foo> result = entityManager.createQuery(select).getResultList();
```

Comment: Did this approach work fine ? can i compare two column builder.notEqual(from.get("col1"), from.get("col2")) at run time in Criteria Query ?

Comment: I can confirm it works, both equal and notEqual accept two Expressions as their parameters.